# Calling a Function from a Database in PHP

Tags: php, eval

I have this requirement that states that I must have a function signature as a value in a database column. So what I need to do is get that value that will then call the function in code. For example....let's say I have a column in a database named "Signature" that has a value of SendMail();. I need to be able to get the return value and then store it in another table. The problem is when I use the eval function on $i['Signature'] the function gets called, but I can't get the return value. What am I doing wrong? Here's an example:

```
$query = "SELECT signature FROM tbl WHERE id = 1 ";
$signature = mysql_query($query);
while ($i = mysql_fetch_array($signature)){
   //Here the function is being called properly but I can't get the return value.
   $email= eval($i['Signature']);
   if(mysql_num_rows($i) == 0){
      //insert the returned value into another table.
      $insertString = "INSERT INTO tbl (email) VALUES ('$email')";
   }
}

function SendMail()
{
   $email= 'Have a great day'
   return $email;
}
```

Also I'm bound to get some "eval is evil" comments, so if there's a better way please advise.

Comment: If you have to stick with eval, at least check that the contents of the Signature column actually are valid first. Maybe via the `function_exists` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned.
```

Therefore you should add `return`:

```
$email= eval('return ' . $i['Signature']);
```

alternatively:

```
eval('$email = '  . $i['Signature']);
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I just read that statement, but didn't fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off storing the name of the function as a string in one column, and the arguments to pass to the function as a serialised array in another column. Then you could use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to get a return value from the function without using `eval()`

Comment: Interesting. I'll give this a shot.